# Asterisk in Nested loops, Java

Tags: java, eclipse, asterisk, nested-loops

I am trying to make my code print out the Asterisk in the image, you see below. The Asterisk are align to the right and they have blank spaces under them. I can't figure out, how to make it go to the right. Here is my code:

```
public class Assn4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            for (int x = 0; x <= 1; x++) {
                System.out.println(" ");
            }

            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a funny loop: `for (int x = 0; x <= 1; x++) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix problems are really helpful to understand loops..

Understanding of your problem:

1) First, printing star at the end- That means your first loop should be in      decreasing order

for(int i =7;i>=0; i+=i-2)

2) Printing star in increasing order- That means your second loop should be in increasing order

for(int j =0;j<=7; j++)

Complete code:

```
for(int i =7;i>=0; i=i-2){ // i=i-2 because *s are getting incremented by 2
     for(int j =0;j<=7; j++){
         if(j>=i){ // if j >= i then print * else space(" ")
            System.out.print("*");
         }
         else{
            System.out.print(" ");
         }
    }
    System.out.println();// a new line just after printing *s

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting loops with `1` can sometimes help you visualize better.

```
int stopAt = 7;
for (int i = 1; i <= stopAt ; i += 2) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= stopAt; j++) {
        System.out.print(j <= stopAt - i ? " " : "*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Notice, how each row prints an odd number of `*`s ending at the line with 7. So, you start with `i` at 1 and go through 3 `1+2`, 5 `3+2`, and then `stopAt` 7 `5+2`.

The nested `for` loop has to print 7 characters always to make sure `*`s appear right aligned. So, the loop runs from `1` to `7`.

Answer (score 0):

Here the complete code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if( i%2 != 0){
            for(int x = 0; x < i; x++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```